# If $m^∗(A) = 0$, then $m^∗(A \cup B) = m^∗(B)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that if $m^∗(A) = 0$, then $m^∗(A \cup B) = m^∗(B)$. I am trying to prove $m^*(A) = 0$ first then prove the second part but I am not sure if that is the right thing to do.

Comment: Is $m^*$ a particular measure?

Comment: No it was not specified so I did not think so

Comment: Well is it a measure at all? You haven't given any context.

Comment: No the question I provided is how it was asked by my teacher in which I am having troubles solving it.

Comment: Elementary logic: to prove that [If $m^∗(A) = 0$, then $m^∗(A \cup B) = m^∗(B)$], one is not required to prove that [$m^∗(A) = 0$ for every $A$] (and this is good that one is not required to do so since [$m^∗(A) = 0$ for every $A$] is just absurd).

Comment: @AlexisOlson Obviously, $m^*$ can be any exterior measure (but the OP should have explained this, yes).

Answer (score 3):

By definition,

$$m^*(A\cup B)\leq \underbrace{m^*(A)}_{=0}+m^*(B)=m^*(B).$$
By monotonicity of $m^*$, since $B\subset A\cup B$, you get $$m^*(B)\leq m^*(A\cup B).$$ The claim is proved.